# design shared memory for MPI using Boost

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, shared-memory, boost-mpi

I would like to ask if someone knows a *boost::mpi* documentation for beginners? (i already read Boost.MPI documentation from the Internet site).

a bit about my system, i have a claster of about 90 knots, each knot have two CPU with two cores (4 cores together) and 4Gb ram.

i would like to define shared memory to each knot and there store a vector `std::vector<bool> occupation;`. Then each process need to compute something based on his `rank()` number.

Now, all the multi Process need to wait until all the cores are done computing and then send  a vector, `std::vector<uint32_t> remove;`, to the main process (`rank() == 0`) which will update vector `occupation` and then send to all the knots the new `occupation` vector.

It could be that it would better to use simply `mpi.h` instead of `boost::mpi`.

I would like to hear your opinion, since i don't have experience in this area of MPI.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`OpenMP`](http://openmp.org) for the shared-memory part if your compiler supports it, then setting up one process per node that does what four processes what do in your current setup. MPI wasn't really designed for shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by larsmans, you can't really do shared memory with MPI.  But it sounds like you don't really need distributed shared memory; it sounds like all of the tasks need to get a copy of `occupation` at the start, do their calculations, send their results back to the master in the form of `remove`, and the master then broadcasts an updated copy of `occupation`.  MPI can do that just fine.

A way to start would be to have the master process use [`broadcast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/broadcast.html) to do the initial sending of data, have the worker processes use [`send`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/communicator.html#id2389555-bb) to send the updates back to the master, and have the master [`recv`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/communicator.html#id2656520-bb) the data from each task; when that's done, the cycle repeats itself.

Comment: thanks for your answer. lets assume `occupation` is of the size of `2^30` bool elements, then each process requires 1Gb, where in realty i only need is one `occupation` vector for all the 4 cores... that was the reason for my question

Comment: One way around this would be to use MPI between nodes, and a threading approach like OpenMP within nodes; then each node only needs one copy, which is fine if you have 4Gb each.   Otherwise, is there some structure to the computation - don all the tasks need all of occupation at the same time?

Comment: `occupation` is the center of the program and most of the computation need to access this vector during the computation. I searched a bit the net and is what i am searching called Hybrid Programming? (combination of MPI and OpenMP)

Comment: Yes.  So you still do what I suggest above -- broadcast the data out, then collect the results with send/recieve; and then use OpenMP (or whatever facilities boost may have for shared-memory stuff) to break the computation up within the node.   Start with one or the other -- doesn't matter which -- and get that working, then add the other.